# adding image inside server side script in datatable

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

i am using datatables server side proceesing for populating data 
how can i add image src here inside table column to get it populated because in database i have its path like "image/car.jpg". i want to concatinate the row with

here is code

```
while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
    {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] == "carimage" )
            {
                /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]; // add  <img src="rent/project/image/car.jpg"> to this row

            }
            else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
            {
                /* General output */
                $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }
```

Comment: i am storing the path in database .. need to concatinate that src but dont know how to bound it inside the datatable

Comment: Do you want to display the image or store the image **path** or the actual **image**?

Comment: display image as i asked  inside data table .

Comment: Check my answer below, I am still not fully understanding what you want, but my answer shows you how to display the image **if** you have got the image path in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it seems that you're struggling to display the image, if you have the path already in the database, all you need to do is loop through all the **image paths** from your db and echo them out like this,

```
echo "<img src=". $getImagePath['yourImagePathColumn'] .'" />";
```

Comment: i have image path inside database i am retriving it in datatables .

Comment: @AsifAli have you tried my answer? All you have to do is put the path directory in the `src` part.

Comment: if you can see datatables is a plugin . i did it myself 
added it this way
'$row[] = "<img src =admin/pages/".$aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ].">";'

Comment: @AsifAli glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

@Script47 is correct but if all you're getting - and all you want to return from the server-side script - is the image name then you could use the a render function on the specified column within the datatable initialization like this:

```
"render": function (data, type, row){
    return "<img src='somepath/"+data+"'/>;
},
```

Comment: I'm not sure what he really wants, he mentions `data tables` however I think he might be using the wrong words.

Comment: i did it this way 
`$row[] = "<img src =admin/pages/".$aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ].">";`